# Why is observable subscribe() not triggered while the async pipe in the template properly refreshing?

Tags: angular, observable

When programmatically setting the service class's observable to a new value using `setAdminLogicalUser()` the template values properly refresh, while the observing code in the component class is not executed.

I presume that the reason for the observing code not to be executed is due to the simple fact that the observable is set to a new instance and therefore any observers are "lost" with the old instance being replaced. However, why is the template able to still refresh, does it internally use another way of subscribing to the observer?

Service:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthService {

      user: Observable<User>;

      constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private afs: AngularFirestore) {

        this.user = this.afAuth.authState
          .switchMap(user => {
            if (user) {
              return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
            } else {
              return Observable.of(null)
            }
       })

       setAdminLogicalUser(uid: string) {
         this.user = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges()
       }
    }
```

Component Template:

```
  <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <!-- following attributes properly refresh after authService.setAdminLogicalUser() -->
    <h1 *ngIf="!auth.isAdmin(user)">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h1>
    ...
```

Component Class:

```
export class ProfileComponent {
  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.user.subscribe(userData => {
      // not executed after authService.setAdminLogicalUser()
      console.log('this.auth.user.subscribe')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the logs(console)? I suppose your ngOnInit subscription would return an error.

Comment: @Avij No errors in the console. Why would it throw an error?

Comment: From Where are you calling this method setAdminLogicalUser? Is it directly from component or template? If this method is not called before you subscribe then your subscription should have thrown an error. Because it is undefined before calling the method. But as you said it is not the case, i want to know from where this method is being called then?

Comment: @Avij `auth.user`is set in the constructor of the service (I left that part out for simplicity). Gonna add it now. `setAdminLogicalUser()` is called afterwards from another component upon a user's change in a select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angular uses change detection and thus evaluates the expressions in the template at each change detection.

It thus detects that `auth.user` has changed, and passes the new value to the `async` pipe.

Whereas the code in `ngOnInit` is executed once and only once, and thus subscribes to the `user` observable that is stored in `auth` at the time `ngOnInit` is executed.

Instead of assigning a new value to the observable, the observable should never change, but you should emit a new value from this observable (i.e. use a Subject).

Comment: Excellent answer and clear explenation. This had me going insane too. I couldn't figure out why the difference. Leaves me one question, why would you ever do a manual subscription in a component? It will never trigger again and thus useless to update values. Oh and I know you can do the ngAfterViewChecked but that causes a lot of errors with detection changes. So, Subject it is.